# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getConnection()

Tags: php

I have this error message..try to extends class but nothing helps..in database.php i have function getConnection()

```
<?php
 require_once 'database.php';

 class userClass {

    /* User Login */

    public function userLogin($username, $password) { 

        try{

$db = getConnection();
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   getConnection()

Comment: `getConnection` where u define this method, what u have inside this file `'database.php'` is Database.php have class or statc methods?

Comment: in database class // get the database connection
    public function getConnection(){
        
        $this->conn = null;
  
        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
  
        return $this->conn;
    }

Comment: if class, then how can u use this `$db = getConnection();` ?? u need to create object of your database class.

Comment: share the code of database.php

Comment: class Database {
  
    // specify your own database credentials
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "";
    private $username = "";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

Comment: // get the database connection
    public function getConnection(){
        
        $this->conn = null;
  
        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
  
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Database class, you have to instanciate an object of this class first.
Based on the excerpt from your `database.php`

```php
<?php
 require_once 'database.php';

 class userClass {

    /* User Login */

    public function userLogin($username, $password) { 

        try{

           $db = new Database();
           $conn = $db->getConnection();

           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it be a function on the object?

Comment: Of course, I just forgot to edit the line - I updated the answer.